# Create kml file using xml elements

Tags: c#, xml, kml

I want to create a kml file in c#. Now I have two problems:

1. What is the synatx to add the kml element in the xml file in order to have the line below in my kml file?

   ```
   <kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
   ```
2. I have an array of points that i would like to form a linestring. How am I suppose to fill the coordinates element in xml for the kml file?.The following is my code so far.

**CODE**:

```
public void MakeKmlFile(string line)
{
    CoordinateCollection coordinates = new CoordinateCollection();

    char[] delimiterLine = { '|' };
    char[] delimiterPoint = { ',' };
    string[] route = line.Split(delimiterLine);

    foreach (string point in route)
    {
        string[] route_point = line.Split(delimiterPoint);
        double lat = double.Parse(route_point[1]);
        double lon = double.Parse(route_point[0]);
        coordinates.Add(new Vector(lat, lon));
    }

    XmlTextWriter writer = new XmlTextWriter("route.xml", System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
    writer.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
    writer.WriteStartElement("Document");
    writer.WriteStartElement("Folder");
    writer.WriteStartElement("name");
    writer.WriteString("route");
    writer.WriteEndElement();
    writer.WriteStartElement("Placemark");
    writer.WriteStartElement("Style");
    writer.WriteStartElement("LineStyle");
    writer.WriteStartElement("color");
    writer.WriteString("ff0000ff");
    writer.WriteEndElement();
    writer.WriteEndElement();
    writer.WriteStartElement("PolyStyle");
    writer.WriteStartElement("fill");
    writer.WriteString("2");
    writer.WriteEndElement();
    writer.WriteEndElement();
    writer.WriteEndElement();
    writer.WriteStartElement("LineString");
    writer.WriteStartElement("coordinates");
```

This is the result i got:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
  <Document>
    <Name>Points.kml</Name>
    <Placemark />
    <Placemark />
    <Placemark />
    <Placemark />
    <Placemark />
  </Document>
```

Comment: Note that PolyStyle fill element has a value of 1 or 0 => "2" is not valid.

Answer (score 3):

You can create the KML document just like a normal XML document

```
    XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
    XmlDeclaration xDec = xDoc.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", null);

    XmlElement rootNode = xDoc.CreateElement("kml");
    rootNode.SetAttribute("xmlns", @"http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2");
    xDoc.InsertBefore(xDec, xDoc.DocumentElement);
    xDoc.AppendChild(rootNode);
    XmlElement docNode = xDoc.CreateElement("Document");
    rootNode.AppendChild(docNode);

    XmlElement nameNodeMain = xDoc.CreateElement("Name");
    XmlText nameTextMain = xDoc.CreateTextNode("Points.kml");
    docNode.AppendChild(nameNodeMain);
    nameNodeMain.AppendChild(nameTextMain);
```

That sets up the basic structure for your document then all you need to do is add each placemark (This is best done through a loop)

```
    char[] delimiterLine = { '|' };
    char[] delimiterPoint = { ',' };
    string[] places = line.Split(delimiterLine);
    for (int i = 0; i < places.length; i++)
        {
            string[] placeMark = places[i].split(delimiterPoint);
            XmlElement placeNode = xDoc.CreateElement("Placemark");
            docNode.AppendChild(placeNode);

            XmlElement nameNode = xDoc.CreateElement("Name");
            XmlText nameText = xDoc.CreateTextNode(placeMark[0]);
            placeNode.AppendChild(nameNode);
            nameNode.AppendChild(nameText);

            XmlElement descNode = xDoc.CreateElement("Description");
            XmlText descText = xDoc.CreateTextNode(placeMark[1]);
            placeNode.AppendChild(descNode);
            descNode.AppendChild(descText);

            XmlElement pointNode = xDoc.CreateElement("Point");
            placeNode.AppendChild(pointNode);

            XmlElement coordNode = xDoc.CreateElement("coordinates");
            XmlText coordText = xDoc.CreateTextNode(string.Format("{0},{1}", placeMark[2], placeMark[3]));
            pointNode.AppendChild(coordNode);
            coordNode.AppendChild(coordText);
        }
        return xDoc;
```

I haven't worked with LineStrings in KML before but I suspect the code to do that would be along the lines of the following:

```
    XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
    XmlDeclaration xDec = xDoc.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", null);

    XmlElement rootNode = xDoc.CreateElement("kml");
    rootNode.SetAttribute("xmlns", @"http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2");
    xDoc.InsertBefore(xDec, xDoc.DocumentElement);
    xDoc.AppendChild(rootNode);
    XmlElement docNode = xDoc.CreateElement("Document");
    rootNode.AppendChild(docNode);

    XmlElement nameNodeMain = xDoc.CreateElement("Name");
    XmlText nameTextMain = xDoc.CreateTextNode("Points.kml");
    docNode.AppendChild(nameNodeMain);
    nameNodeMain.AppendChild(nameTextMain);

XmlElement placeNode = xDoc.CreateElement("Placemark");
docNode.AppendChild(placeNode);

XmlElement nameNode = xDoc.CreateElement("Name");
XmlText nameText = xDoc.CreateTextNode("Test line");
placeNode.AppendChild(nameNode);
nameNode.AppendChild(nameText);

XmlElement lineStringNode = xDoc.CreateElement("LineString");
placeNode.AppendChild(lineStringNode);

XmlElement coordNode = xDoc.CreateElement("coordinates");

char[] delimiterLine = { '|' };
    char[] delimiterPoint = { ',' };
    string[] places = line.Split(delimiterLine);
    for (int i = 0; i < places.length; i++)
    {
    string[] placeMark = places[i].split(delimiterPoint);

    XmlText coordText = xDoc.CreateTextNode(string.Format("{0},{1}", placeMark[0], placeMark[1]));
    pointNode.AppendChild(coordNode);
   }


coordNode.AppendChild(coordText);

xDoc.Save("./KML/");
```

It basically involves moving my previous code around and creating a single XmlElement for each of the main elements required in a KML file and then iterating through the coordinates after splitting them in the line string.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Since I want to end with a linestring element from an array of points how shall i go about it in the placemark for each loop? @Donald Dunlop

Comment: I'm assuming your linestring is in the format of "place|place|place" and each "place" is made up for place = "Name,Description,Latitude,Longitude" for that what would can do is use your the array received from Split("|") and then do a for loop iterating through that array and splitting each element within using the "," character.

Comment: I've changed the foreach loop to a for loop that makes use of the splitting of a linestring

Comment: Now how am i suppose to see the result. Would it be saved somewhere? @Donald Dunlop

Comment: You can use xDoc.Save("Filename") to save the XML file to a specific file destination to check if it worked correctly

Comment: I have updated the question with the result I got when I saved it. What went wrong? @Donald Dunlop

Comment: It is creating a new element for each point. Since i would like to create a linestring only one element i want to be created as a linestring containing all the points in it

Comment: I added some additional code at the bottom of my original solution that should potentially move more towards the solution you're looking for. What the snippets above demonstrate for the most part is the structure for generating XML/KML files dynamically. You may just need to move some of the functions around a bit to get the format correct

Answer (score 0):

Most direct solution is to tokenize the route (line string) and append coordinates in a string buffer then output as a value. No need to create the CoordinateCollection and separate Vector objects.

NOTE: In order to be valid KML you must output the longitude value first then latitude separated by comma (,) with no whitespace between the lon-lat values and whitespace must separate each lon-lat pair optionally with an altitude value.

Here's C# solution using the [*System.Xml.XmlTextWriter*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w703ce6s%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) class:

```
    XmlTextWriter writer = new XmlTextWriter(...);
    writer.WriteStartElement("kml", "http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2");
    ...
    writer.WriteStartElement("LineString");
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (string point in route)
    {
        string[] route_point = point.Split(delimiterPoint);
        if (route_point.Length >= 2)
        {
          double lon = double.Parse(route_point[0]);
          double lat = double.Parse(route_point[1]);
          sb.Append(' ').Append(lon).Append(',').Append(lat);
          // coordinates.Add(new Vector(lat, lon));
        }
    }
    writer.WriteStartElement("coordinates");
    writer.WriteValue(sb.ToString());
    writer.WriteEndElement(); // end coordinates
    writer.WriteEndElement(); // end LineString
    writer.WriteEndElement(); // end Placemark
    ...
    writer.Close();
```